# Leaflet-routing-machine. L is not define (IonicV1)

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine, ionic-v1

i am using leaflet routing machine(liedman) in ionicV1 project. I did everything according to tutorial, i got error

[L. is not define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5BbK.jpg)

I read other post about put leaflet link between  tag, i did everything.

**CSS**

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-
0.7.3/leaflet.css" />-->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"/>-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet-routing-machine-
3.2.5/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css"/>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-routing-machine.css"/>
```

**JS link**

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js">
</script>-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<!--<script src="lib/leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.5/dist/leaflet-routing-
machine.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="lib/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>-->
```

**tag**

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<!--<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js">
</script>-->
<!--<script src="lib/leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.5/dist/leaflet-routing-
machine.js"></script>-->
<script src="leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
```

**aap.js**

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([57,74, 11.949], 10);;

var map= L.tileLayer('Company server link, this link working fine', {
attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
waypoints: [
L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
],
routeWhileDragging: true
}).addTo(map);
```

I commented other link , because i try everything but still not figure it out, i am stuck in this BASIC problem since 2 days. Anyone ?

Answer (score 2):

Load Leaflet **before** your application code.

Instead of

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Do something like

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: …and `leaflet-routing-machine.js` in between :-)

Comment: between in <head> or <body>

Comment: btw i just load <script src="js/app.js"> after div id and before **leaflet-routing-machine** , map now showing but got new error. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'control' of undefined**